# Accessing text field with multiple values in a twig file

Tags: theming

Here is my use case: I have a content type which has a field referencing multiple other entities. Those entities have a text field with multiple values.

So I do

```
{% for ref in node.field_references %}
```

and then inside the loop

```
ref.entity.title.value
```

To have the `title` of the referenced entity. This works. Then I try to list the values in the text field:

```
for value in ref.entity.field_name_of_text_field
```

But without success. Is there something else that must be done first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both loops iterate field items, so when you name the loop variables accordingly the code should be more understandable:

```
{% for ref_item in node.field_references %}
  {% for text_item in ref_item.entity.field_name_of_text_field %}
    {{ text_item.value }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```